# Cambiar datos de un Json en PHP

Tags: php, json, php5

Tengo un json el cual me almacena datos de un producto y deseo cambiar dichos datos pero solo a los que el producto tenga su código:

```
"items": [
    {
      "id": "2050144",
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Split Mabe MMT12CDBWLCCE8 12.000 BTU - Color Blanco 100058314",
      "refId": "100058314",
      "price": 40232,
      "listPrice": 67054,
      "tax": 4827,
      "bodega": 397
    },
    {
      "id": "2004254",
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Refrigeradora Electrolux ERT44K6CMG  440 Litros - Color Gris 100046374",
      "refId": "100046374",
      "price": 48794,
      "listPrice": 111161,
      "tax": 5855,
      "bodega": 397
    }
  ]
```

Es decir, dentro de `items` al que tenga `refId=100058314` cambiar el valor de la 
`bodega=347` he intentado esto:

```
foreach ($items as $item):
                if ($item['refId']==$idref) {
                    $item['bodega']=$idbodega;
                }
            endforeach;
```

Pero no funciona, agradeceria mucho su ayuda
 utilizando la función `vardump(items)` esta me bota el siguiente resultado:

```
    array(2) {
  [
    0
  ]=>
  array(8) {
    [
      "id"
    ]=>
    string(7) "2050144"
    [
      "quantity"
    ]=>
    int(1)
    [
      "name"
    ]=>
    string(61) "Split Mabe MMT12CDBWLCCE8 12.000 BTU - Color Blanco 100058314"
    [
      "refId"
    ]=>
    string(9) "100058314"
    [
      "price"
    ]=>
    int(40232)
    [
      "listPrice"
    ]=>
    int(67054)
    [
      "tax"
    ]=>
    int(4827)
    [
      "bodega"
    ]=>
    int(397)
  }
  [
    1
  ]=>
  array(8) {
    [
      "id"
    ]=>
    string(7) "2004254"
    [
      "quantity"
    ]=>
    int(1)
    [
      "name"
    ]=>
    string(70) "Refrigeradora Electrolux ERT44K6CMG  440 Litros - Color Gris 100046374"
    [
      "refId"
    ]=>
    string(9) "100046374"
    [
      "price"
    ]=>
    int(48794)
    [
      "listPrice"
    ]=>
    int(111161)
    [
      "tax"
    ]=>
    int(5855)
    [
      "bodega"
    ]=>
    int(397)
  }
}
```

Por lo que no sé como poder cambiar los valores que necesito cambiar.

Comment: Has intentado tratarlos como objeto? Es decir, en lugar de seleccionar la posición de un array uses una propiedad, de esta forma `$item->refId`?

Comment: el problema es que al intentar recorrer a "items" no me deja y me sale error

Comment: Solo para asegurar, hiciste json_decode()?, puedes mostrar que error sale?

Comment: lo que pasa es que estoy utilizando api para retornar los datos pero me sale en blanco debido a que no permite recorrer a item porque cuando lo elimino me muestra datos anexos

Comment: @WilliamFerruzola ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta ya agregar el resultado que hacer `var_dump($items)`?

Comment: @Marcos ya edite la pregunta y utilice vardump

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` hace una copia de cada elemento y las modificaciones se hacen en la copia. Para modificar los elementos originales usa la referencia:

```
foreach ($items as &$item)
```