# Recorrer Array asociativo PHP

Tags: php

Saludos acudo a ustedes debido a que no puedo recorrer u array asociativo, el array es el siguiente:

```
"items": [
{
  "id": "2050144",
  "quantity": 1,
  "name": "Split Mabe MMT12CDBWLCCE8 12.000 BTU - Color Blanco 100058314",
  "refId": "100058314",
  "price": 40232,
  "listPrice": 67054,
  "tax": 4827,
  "bodega": 397
},
{
  "id": "2004254",
  "quantity": 1,
  "name": "Refrigeradora Electrolux ERT44K6CMG  440 Litros - Color Gris 100046374",
  "refId": "100046374",
  "price": 48794,
  "listPrice": 111161,
  "tax": 5855,
  "bodega": 397
}
  ]
```

lo recorro de esta forma:

```
foreach (items as $itemp) :
                $r=$itemp->refId;
                if ($itemp->refId == 100058314) {
                    $r="siiii";                 
                }
endforeach;
```

lo que necesito hacer es cambiar el valor de la bodega cuando el campo refId sea igual al que envio, pero no logro poder recorrer el array 
agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Cambiar datos de un Json en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306360/cambiar-datos-de-un-json-en-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un JSON, no?
En ese caso hay que hacer así:

```
<?php

$items =<<<JSON
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "2050144",
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Split Mabe MMT12CDBWLCCE8 12.000 BTU - Color Blanco 100058314",
      "refId": "100058314",
      "price": 40232,
      "listPrice": 67054,
      "tax": 4827,
      "bodega": 397
    },
    {
      "id": "2004254",
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Refrigeradora Electrolux ERT44K6CMG  440 Litros - Color Gris 100046374",
      "refId": "100046374",
      "price": 48794,
      "listPrice": 111161,
      "tax": 5855,
      "bodega": 397
    }]
}
JSON;

$json = json_decode($items);
foreach($json->items as &$item) {
  if ($item->refId == "100058314") {
    $item->bodega = 1234; // <- Este sería el nuevo valor
  }
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es casi correcta, pero tiene tres errore. 1º No hay por qué forzar a array el JSON. Cambia esto: `$json = json_decode($items);` por esto: **`$json = json_decode($items, true);`**. 2º. Si haces una comparación estricta no funcionará, porque los datos del JSON en la clave `refId` son cadenas, no números, por tanto debes ponerlo así: **`if ($item->refId == 100058314) {`**  3º. Debes cerrar esta línea con el punto y coma: **`$item->bodega = 1234;`**  Así funcionará a la perfección.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo corregí en la nueva edición

Comment: y si tuviera mas items? ahora puede que sean 2 pero si se va actualizando el archivo a mas?

Comment: Es lo mismo "foreach" recorre todo el array.